# Is it a whole number?

Tags: code-golf, number, decision-problem, integer

A number is [whole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number) if it is a non-negative integer with no decimal part. So `0` and `8` and `233494.0` are whole, while `1.1` and `0.001` and `233494.999` are not.

---

### Input

A floating-point number in the default base/encoding of your language.

For example, the default integer representation for [Binary Lambda Calculus](//esolangs.org/wiki/Binary_lambda_calculus) would be [Church numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding). But the default integer representation for [Python](//python.org) is [*base 10 decimal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal), not [Unary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_numeral_system).

### Output

A [truthy](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2194/60919) value if the input is whole, a [falsy](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2194/60919) value if it is not.

Note that if your language only supports decimal precision to, say, 8 places, `1.000000002` can be considered whole.

Input and output may be done via any [standard I/O methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/61563).

---

## Test cases

```
Input        -> Output
332          -> true
33.2         -> false
128239847    -> true
0.128239847  -> false
0            -> true
0.000000000  -> true
1.111111111  -> false
-3.1415926   -> false
-3           -> false
```

---

## Scoring

As with [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest submission wins. Good luck!

Comment: @StephenLeppik It's no easier than the vanilla parity challenge, or the Hello World, or the Truth Machine. (In fact, it's harder than most of those.)

Comment: May we take input as two numbers, representing a fraction?

Comment: @LyricLy No, that would either be much easier for some languages or unnecessary for others.

Comment: Note that whole numbers are non-negative integers.  Please update your first sentence to reflect this.  And you can add in negative numbers test cases if you wish to show how whole numbers are not negative and falsy outputs for negative numbers are valid.

Comment: "Output may be deterministic"? I suppose you meant "Output must be deterministic"

Comment: "Non-negative integers" implies no decimal part, by the nature of what an integer is.  Do you mean to specify "Non-negative numbers with no decimal part", or no?  Yes I'm splitting hairs over grammar.

Comment: @ThomasWard I'm just making sure it's perfectly clear.

Comment: @MDXF web browser caching, sorry.

Comment: Should `-0` returns truthy? At least by now the Retina answer get it wrong. What about `1.0`?

Comment: @user202729 Unless you're doing assembly, `-0` evaluates to its simplest form `0`, and that's what should be inputted. `1.0` evaluates to its simplest form `1`, and that's what should be inputted.

Comment: Must we return a truthy value or can we have true/false inverted in our output?

Comment: Now the Ly answer cannot handle `1` but can handle `1.0`. Is that valid?

Comment: How do you represent non-integer numbers with church numerals?

Comment: Can we define what we consider truthy? (e.g. can 0 be true, and 1 be false).

Comment: There are missing test cases like -1.0  ;  1.0  ;  500.000  ;  -500.000

Comment: @TomCarpenter No, that's not allowed by concensus

Comment: @ThomasWard, that wikipedia article seems to not fully agree with you: "Texts that exclude zero from the natural numbers sometimes refer to the natural numbers together with zero as the whole numbers, but in other writings, that term is used instead for the integers (including negative integers)". I read the title as asking about integers.

Comment: @ilkkachu Whole Number != Natural Number if I recall my math right.  they are separate concepts.

Comment: In a language like Befunge, where there aren't really different data types, can we take in numbers like so: `123.0000617`?

Comment: Sinclair ZX80 (4K ROM) has integer-only BASIC, so on that basis am I allowed an entry for this technology? i.e., any floating point number will produce an error (false), so I only need to check for numbers of zero or more.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 3 bytes

```apl
⌊≡|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RHPV2POhfWADkKxsZGXCBSD0QZGlkYGVtamJgD2QZ6KDywiAEMgNTqGcIAkHdovbGeoYmhqaWRGYQHAA)

Note that `f←` has been prepended in the TIO link due to technical limitations, but it's not normally needed.

Comment: That's elegant! I don't know why I added unnecessary ceiling to my answer....

Comment: @GalenIvanov This is just `floor(n) == abs(n)`.

Answer (score 16):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>27</s> 16 bytes

This function checks whether `x` is contained in the list of nonnegative integers that are not greater than `x`.

```hs
f x=elem x[0..x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hwjY1JzVXoSLaQE@vIvZ/bmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JgkaagrGeoYmhqaaCgp0dsqABEGiiiGnoGmpq/gcA)

Answer (score 10):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>17</s> <s>15</s> 14 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to Not a tree!*

```
#>=0==#~Mod~1&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2Zl@1/ZztbA1la5zjc/pc5Q7X9AUWZeSbRGtbJOWrRybK2apr5DtbGxkY6xsZ6RjqGRhZGxpYWJuY6BHhIbyDOAAR1DPUMY0NE11jM0MTS1NDIDMmtj/wMA)

First Mathematica answer \o/

### Mathematica, 15 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @user202729!*

```
#==⌊Abs@#⌋&
```

Answer (score 10):

## Pyth, 4 bytes

```
qs.a
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=qs.a&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=332%0A33.2%0A128239847%0A0.128239847%0A0%0A0.000000000%0A1.111111111%0A-3.1415926%0A-3&debug=0)

Is the number equal (`q`) to the floor (`s`) of its absolute value (`.a`)?

Answer (score 6):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 3 bytes

```
£ΘN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6vkKtR/KipsUjz0Lb/hxafm@H3//9/Y2MjLmNjPSMuQyMLI2NLCy4DPSjLxJzLAMgzgAEuQz1DGODSNdYzNDE0tTQyAzIB)
The third test case times out in TIO, so I chopped off a couple of digits.
I tried to run it locally, but killed it after a couple of minutes since it was using over 6GB of memory and my computer started to stutter.
It should theoretically finish at some point...

### Explanation

This corresponds to the challenge description pretty directly.

```
£ΘN  Implicit input: a number.
  N  The infinite list [1,2,3,4...
 Θ   Prepend 0: [0,1,2,3,4...
£    Is the input an element of this list?
```

Comment: What would `λx → floor(x) == abs(x)` look like in Husk?

Comment: @Lynn That would be `§=⌊a`, so one byte longer.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 18 bytes

```python
lambda n:n%1==0<=n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKk/V0NbWwMY2739icXFqUYlCmoaxsZGmQmaxQkhRaSoXkqgeRNgtMacYSdzQyMLI2NLCxByLHgM9VFk0rQZYtRjAABZZQz1DGMBmoK6xnqGJoamlkRl2WSTRgqLMvBINJcecHIWS1OKSYoUCkLoUPSXN/wA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/) and [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>21</s> 18 bytes

```python
lambda n:n>=0==n%1
```

[Try it online! (Py2)](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKs/O1sDWNk/V8H9BUWZeiUaahrGxkaYmF4Knh8w1NLIwMra0MDFHEjPQwyqKosIABpDN0jOEASRRXWM9QxNDU0sjMxRBTc3/AA)
[Try it online! (Py3)](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKs/O1sDWNk/V8H9BUWZeiUaahrGxkaYmF4Knh8w1NLIwMra0MDFHEjPQwyqKosIABpDN0jOEASRRXWM9QxNDU0sjMxRBTc3/AA)

3 bytes saved thanks to Mr. XCoder.

Answer (score 5):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 94 bytes, input hard-coded

```
/=/\/x://:/\/\///-0/-:.0/.:.|/|:-|/|:0=1=2=3=4=5=6=7=8=9=|x/|:||/true:x:/-:/.:/|/+:++/false/||
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYw7DoAgFAQPRGDxry/Zm9BQYCyoRBOKd3fEZqeYzJYcy5VKayACqgDSGQBYDyvOw4lTqNh/PAeOnDhz4cqNOw9q7UIVz/0m6QdWegKFEWNwxlwSVFv7AA)

Input between the two terminating vertical lines (`||`)

Strips `-00...0` and `.00...0`, converts all remaining digits to `x`s, then tests whether the remaining number still has `x`s after `.` or a `-` not followed by `.`.

Could save up to 7 bytes depending on what's counted as truthy and falsey since this language doesn't have native truthy/falsey values, currently is outputting `true` and `false` but could change to, for example, `T` and `F` for 87 bytes if that's allowed.

Answer (score 5):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 15 bytes

```matlab
@(x)any(x==0:x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0IzMa9So8LW1sCqQvN/moaxsZECFGgqKKgqlBSVpnKBhPWMkIXTEnOKQeKGRhZGxpYWJuaoyg304BIoyg0UFLCZbqBnAAPIwoZ6hjCAYoqusZ6hiaGppZGZApo4qulg8f8A)

This one is based on the approach used in [@flawr's Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/148476/42295).

While it brings the byte count down to 15, it is shamefully inefficient (no offence intended), creating a list of every integer from `0` to `x` and seeing if `x` is contained within.

---

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 18 bytes

```matlab
@(x)fix(x)==abs(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYxJCoAwDEX3niIbQReGJnVcFLxKFQuCIDjh7euAihX/IoH3P6@vJ7001ihEtGWwhqZd96uUrsb9WxNIyXAlBPBhGubGOzDyGxvdjQcnzlkWeZy5c4FP4cwFwJ9doLjzxoR0x7FEEimmpOAUPty1n9xu)

Takes input as a double precision number. Returns true if whole.

Checks if the input when rounded is equal to the magnitude of the input. This will only be the case when the number is positive and whole.

---

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 18 bytes

```matlab
@(x)~mod(x,+(x>0))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0KzLjc/RaNCR1ujws5AU/N/moaxsZECFGgqKKgqlBSVpnKBhPWMkIXTEnOKQeKGRhZGxpYWJuaoyg304BIoyg0UFLCZbqBnAAPIwoZ6hjCAYoqusZ6hiaGppZGZApo4qulg8f8A)

An alternate solution for 18 bytes. Sadly the `mod` function in Octave won't implicitly convert a `bool` to a `double`, so the `+( )` is needed around the greater than comparison. Otherwise this solution would have been shorter.

---

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 18 bytes

```matlab
@(x)x>=0&~mod(x,1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0Kzws7WQK0uNz9Fo0LHUPN/moaxsZECFGgqKKgqlBSVpnKBhPWMkIXTEnOKQeKGRhZGxpYWJuaoyg304BIoyg0UFLCZbqBnAAPIwoZ6hjCAYoqusZ6hiaGppZGZApo4qulg8f8A)

And another one... <s>I can't seem to get lower than 18 bytes</s>. All because of having to allow for 0 to be true with the `>=` instead of just `>`.

Answer (score 5):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 33 bytes

```cpp
int f(float x){return(uint)x==x;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU9di4MwEHz3Vyz0xdBUNGnvzqr3R45SJCZHQGPRDciJv91bE@g87NcMw6x6vS6/Su0n61TvOw21HWecdDt879YhmNT0Y4uwsHXS6CeXejqzpWmWaguKobUuZcmaACGKnR/mnwc0sIKUgkuZCcML8XX95HlGXciSZsNzWnMCkVnxhuEXmRXX4laKj2OGrYre45TO9k8/EZC884paDWUF5zOyoIgZDszY3e9q9KSo6YcQCB/s2AKlXddH1y3U@Bt5Jtv@Dw)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 6 bytes

```
&gQZsI
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Xy09MKrY8/9/XWM9AwMDAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto), 6 bytes

```
rfdi±=p
```

```
r grabs input
f converts it to a float
d and i duplicates it and converts it to an integer
± pushes the absolute value of it (b/c can't be negative)
= checks if they are equal
p prints out the result
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOLcn//78oLSXz0Ebbgv//jfUMDMwB)

Answer (score 4):

## C (gcc), <s>27</s> <s>28</s> <s>27</s> 25 bytes

*<sup>-2 thanks to PrincePolka</sup>*

```
#define g(f)!fmod(f,f>=0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/fCoIwGMXvfYqlCBvocJuRUvkk3Yz90YGbkRZC9OrZivBCPZfnd873cURaCzFFxon2LhU4WT40uKmmSCptnAI11GinbSehTnR1ztBMBtUPgvcKjghcb8YNGoaxBDDW6OLCxDdHlIARHYPAQ2C5cfDRGYmCZwC85j5jFGc@tjAxXXqEFpSVRX5YxzM8wzXaSGc/rR5g8teSpAyTnOzLDf975TX5EW@hW173U9raDw)

Defines a macro "function" `g` that takes a parameter `f` (of any type). Then checks if casting `f mod 1` is zero, and if `f` is non-negative.

Comment: I think you are required to include the size of the `include` directive in your byte count, since fmod is defined in `math.h` : [see there](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8288/72535)

Comment: @HatsuPointerKun It works [without it too](https://tio.run/##bY/RCoIwGIXv9xTLUDbQsTkjJepJupFtvwx0RkoI0au3VoQX6rk83zn/z1FZo5T3e23AOoMbAnQHXa8JpIImCVzOfIajGUZVD4ZMFN/u1o1AolhjEgO9uigN5YmmeKInhALEXW0defRWU/REOGjuS5kzHmILk@VLT@RlLquyOK7jnM1wjTbS/KfVAyb@WpJMMlGIQ7Xhf6@8fBjxVtDWzeCztvsA)

Comment: I don't think you need -lm on windows-based C distributions (works on my machine)

Comment: 25 ,  #define g(f)!fmod(f,f>=0)

Answer (score 4):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 17 bytes

```
?(:=int(a))*(a>0)
```

### Explanation

```
?             PRINT
 (:=int(a))     if the input (: assigns the cmd line param to 'a') equals itself 
                cast to int, -1 else 0
 *              times
 (a>0)          if the input > 0, -1 else 0
```

If either check fails, this returns 0. If both are true, it returns -1 x -1 = 1

Answer (score 4):

### C#, Java : 43 bytes

-1 byte thanks to Zacharý
-1 byte thanks to TheLetalCoder

```java
int w(float n){return(n==(int)n&&n>=0)?1:0;}
```

C# has a special 33 bytes optimization that you can not do in java :

```cs
bool w(float n){return(int)n==n;}
```

#### For testing

C# code :

```cs
class Program {
    int w(float n){return(n==(int)n&&n>=0)?1:0;}

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Program();
        float[] fTab = new float[]{
            332,33.2f,128239847,0.128239847f,0,0.0000f,1.1111111111f,-3.1415926f,-3
        };
        foreach (float f in fTab) {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} = {1}", f, (p.w(f) != 0).ToString()));
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Java Code :

```java
public class MainApp {
    int w(float n){return(n==(int)n&&n>=0)?1:0;}

    public static void main(String[]a) {
        MainApp m = new MainApp();
        float testArr[] = new float[]{
                332,33.2f,128239847,0.128239847f,0,0.0000f,1.1111111111f,-3.1415926f,-3
        };

        for (float v : testArr) {
            System.out.println(v + " = " + String.valueOf(m.w(v)!=0));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can remove a space between `return` and `(`.

Comment: return a `bool` and there's no need for the ternary.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder `bool` does not exist in Java

Comment: I don't know Java/C# that well, but can you make it `return(int)n==n`? Or would that cast `n==n` to an int rather than just `n`?

Comment: @Zacharý It works in C#, because i can use the `bool` data type. In java, if i want to use a boolean data type, i have to type `boolean`.

Comment: You can lower the Java 7 answer by 3 bytes by reversing the check and changing the boolean operator to a bitwise one: `int w(float n){return(int)n!=n|n<0?0:1;}` (**40 bytes**). As Java 8 lambda it's even shorter: [`n->(int)n==n&n>=0` (**17 bytes**)](https://tinyurl.com/ycotve63), and same applies to the C# answer as lambda: [`n=>(int)n==n&n>=0` (also **17 bytes**)](https://tinyurl.com/y7x5om2r).

Answer (score 4):

## Google Sheets, 10 Bytes

Anonymous worksheet function that tales input from cell `A1` and outputs to the calling cell.

```c
=A1=Int(A1
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 24 bytes

```
f(X):-X>=0,round(X)=:=X.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/P00jQtNKN8LO1kCnKL80LwXItbWyjdADyRgbGWnqcQFpYz0Iw9DIwsjY0sLEHMwz0EPjQ0UNYACiR88QBsB8XWM9QxNDU0sjMyhXUw8A)

Answer (score 3):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), <s>35</s> 47 bytes

```
ir"-"=[0u;]pr[["0"=![psp>l"."=[ppr!u;]p<2$]pp]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z@zSElXyTbaoNQ6tqAoOlrJQMlWMbqguMAuR0kPKF5QUKQIkrIxUoktKIiN/f/fxMhYz8DUxAgA)

Ly has float support, but the only way to create a float currently is by performing division. There is no way to take a float as input, so I had to manually check the string instead.

Lost 13 bytes adding support for negative numbers.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 14

```
n=>!(n<0||n%1)
```

Comment: 13 bytes: `n=>!(n-(n|0))`

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel. It doesn't work for negative numbers.

Comment: @ThePirateBay Which exact number? I tried with 5, 5.1, -5, -5.1, 0, 0.1 and -0.1.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel. `(n=>!(n-(n|0)))(-3)` returns `true`, but should return `false`. See the last test case.

Comment: Oh, you're right on that :/ I mis-read the question :/

Answer (score 3):

## Perl 5, 11 +1(-p) bytes

```
$_=abs==int
```

The `-l` switch not counted because for tests display

[try it online](https://tio.run/##TccxDoAgDEDRvedwhdAWFAbOYjRxICFAhPNbXUj80/vturMTWfZ4nD3GVIYIMwGzJkDyxMHbDYz@@TszA9Q4M6BYo0UXaP341DZSLV1Uyy8)

Answer (score 3):

### C, C++ : <s>38</s> 37 bytes

-1 byte thanks to Zacharý

-1 byte thanks to ceilingcat

```cpp
int w(float n){return(int)n==n&n>=0;}
```

#### For Testing

C : [Try it online](https://tio.run/##PU/BboMwDL33K6xMrRI1jULSdaUp3YdsPSBKViQWpmDUA@LbmYGt72A/y8/PdrH7KorxpQpF3d1KOLd4qxp1v4xVQHhwXzc5QhB9LLGLAUKWceqIsNmES6bdMOu@8ypwAf0KCMuI/7hCBj1Ya6S1yniZmKOx6XH/JrV6ci81lZpAApU84eXOqmSfvKbmMHEY3Gw@bcOF@iYCB6Qt2lE6Q@pgu8X/Myb8RNJ7ztaeVOv2MzBJh@FVTp9RFu8MY1eyE/N13pZMLM7DHP8@1m41jL8)

C Code :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    float f[] = { 332,33.2f,128239847,0.128239847f,0,0.0000f,1.1111111111f,-3.1415926f,-3 };
    int t;
    for ( t = 0; t < 9; ++t) {
        printf("%f = %s\n", f[t], w(f[t])?"true":"false");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

C++ Code :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::initializer_list <std::pair<float,bool>> test{
        {332.f,true}, {33.2f,false}, {128239847.f,true}, {0.128239847f,false}, {0.f,true}, {0.000000f,true}, {1.111111f,false}, {-3.1415926f,false}, {-3.f,false}
    };

    for (const auto& a : test) {
        if (w(a.first) != a.second) {
            std::cout << "Error with " << a.first << '\n';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will only work up to `INT_MAX`. (I don't really care but some people do.)

Comment: Would changing it to `return(int)n==n...` work?

Comment: You can shave one byte by using unsigned int instead of a signed one (as you then don't need the `>=0` test): `return(unsigned)n==n;`  And in C, you can omit the return type for a further 4 bytes.

Comment: You can save 8 more bytes: `w(float n){n=n==(int)n&&n>=0;}`

Answer (score 3):

## C#, <s>40</s> <s>37</s> 29 bytes

```
bool z(float x)=>x%1==0&x>=0;
```

Saved 8 bytes thanks to @Dennis_E!

Old Answer (37 bytes)

```
bool z(float x){return x%1==0&&x>=0;}
```

Old old answer (40 bytes):

```
bool z(float x){return (int)x==x&&x>=0;}
```

Comment: 30 bytes: `bool z(float x)=>x%1==0&&x>=0;` and you can use a single `&` for 29 bytes

Comment: `x=>x%1==0&x>=0` is shorter and compile to `Func<float, bool>`

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>15</s>  13 bytes

```perl6
{.narrow~~UInt}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##ZY5PT4NAEMXv@ykmTRXWwpRdKraSNl6966n2QOiSkCywsot/QugX8@YXQ6gt0vhOk99782aUKGXQVlrAW4BxSLJPuI6LvYB1W2MelWXxfjg8P@amaTvrwQhtYA0yzYW26fcXaiVTY89f9A1Y7saCbphTzCJ1X8MMt97OAdyyHYhXsExZCQsa0l976opComSUw@zYGpKkKE8H3A3Y0zRXlXFgKj6UiI3YU6gJQKqhf@9k05HvwOQXYpIZ27piXFu0rxoSKGObTkjT@j6HQV2if4z4PvIxTCKpBWF8yf3VcnE3jno4wkPUA/jf6qF31h9kyM4a7bs@sgW7XfEALuhl65H@AA)

```perl6
{.Int==$_>=0}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##ZY5PT4NAEMXv@ykmDbpgYcruVmwlNF69e6uNIXRJSBaK7GI0hE/mzS@G0D9I4ztNfu/NmyllpYKu1hI@AkxCkn/BbXLYS4i6Bp8LE0XW2yby2643nozUBiJQWSG17fx8oy5VZuzFq74D6m0o9MPCwTwuHxuY49bfuYBbtgP5DtRUtaTQkuHWS18UklLFBcyPrSFJD9X5gLcB28qKsjYuWPKzlImRewcaApBpGJ47287Ed2F2gpjmxqY3jGvqDFVjAlViOzPSdkJwGNUnhseIEMinMI2VloTxFRfr1fJhGvVxgseoD/C/1Uf/oj/IkF002fcEsiW7X/MAruh165H@Ag)

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 14 bytes

```java
n->n%1==0&n>=0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZBBa4QwEIXv/oq5dFHQrNFtu9uip14LhT2WHrKaLHHdRMy4UIq/3UZTi7UDyZB8897Aq9iNRbrhqiovQ9OdallAUTNj4JVJBV8ewM@vQYa23bQs4WqZf8RWqvP7B7D2bIJpFKCyfqRDWRPRqQKlVuRFWwP@1vJSFgw5iGxQUa7uaJbFG5Vn8fA8SctpzvohN2ggs45pmoTwW9stRDlg23ELyII4IFhtuEeTfZIe9rvHcCWJyRItJfFix0oSzxX@AZTQuVZeUUrojt4fkocQ1uT/FkfGd@8yELoF3wUxxfDkwpjTBTh@GuRXojskjY0fa@ULMs744xUEzqb3xtMP3w)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, <s>17</s> 15 bytes

```
_=>_<0?0:_==~~_
```

```
_=>_<0?0:_==(_|0)
```

Thanks to edc65 for catching my mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

## Unexpanded Sinclair ZX81, 20 bytes

```
 1 INPUT A
 2 PRINT ABS A=INT A
```

20 bytes because BASIC is tokenized.

Simply will output 1 (true) if number is positive and the value of the number entered equals its integer value. Outputs 0 either of those conditions are not met.

Comment: Is this a tokenized language? If it is you should indicate that in your answer.

Comment: Sorry, yes it to tokenized, i.e., INPUT is 1 byte of RAMs, as is PRINT and even >= due to a ~quirk~ intended feature of Sinclair BASIC

Comment: Specifically, each line number is 5 bytes + 1 `newline` (`\r\n` equivalent in ZX81 speak), white spaces don't count as bytes as those are already included in the keywords usually due to the Sinclair 'one-key-press' entry system. On running, it will take more bytes as it will put the value of `A` onto the `var stack`; I think each numeric value is always 5 bytes of memory.

Comment: and ZX Spectrum too

Comment: I'm not sure how the tokenizer works on the Sinclair ZX Spectrum; I do know that I can save bytes by more typing on both machines, but then that confuses the CodeGolf issue somewhat. So if I used `NOT PI` instead of `0` then I save some bytes because `NOT PI` is 2 bytes whereas 0 is 5 bytes or something.

Comment: As far as I know the tokenization mode is exactly the same (Spectrum has more codes). And any literal number is 6 bytes: a 'numeric tag' byte followed by the value encoded in a 5 bytes proprietary floating point format)

Comment: @edc65 very good there - are you making some ZX softwares?

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 11 bytes

```javascript
n=>n<0==n%1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcxBDoIwEAXQPafoxqTVMrQFFYLlIsZIg4VosBCoXr9qDFjiX8zi5c@/qacaq@Ha29B0F@1q6YwszIFJaVbc5UEZxLFAc8IC2eGh3wjCx1q1ow64SEWcpcnerzLweK4yhP5XGbApP@TAp3j/YQw84dtM7NBCl6tfLWHQfasqjSMMaxIWnxvdG4rPVFNLZFF1ZuxaDW3X4GONN5pQeyIkdy8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
ḞA=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjnmOtv///zc2NtIxNtYz0jE0sjAytrQwMdcx0ENiA3kGMKBjqGcIAzq6xnqGJoamlkZmQCYA)

The algorithm is the same as the one used in the [Mathematica answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/148448) above.

Comment: No, it's not a bug that you can't explicitly state a `0` integer part, it's a feature, and specifically a syntax rule that dictates that a leading `0` is a `0` on its own, so for example `053` is the same as `0 53` and `0.5` is the same as `0 .5`.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Nice. But when will you need 2 consecutive nilad?

Comment: A couple of cases would be a dyad-nilad pair followed by a nilad-dyad pair and a quick which takes multiple nilads in a row (specifically `ƭ` = tie), and a third case would be something like a trailing `(dyad)(nilad)(nilad)` or `(monad)(nilad)` or `(dyad)(nilad)(nilad)(monad)` or even `(monad)(nilad)(monad)` etc.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Apparently `ƭ` is one of the quicks that does not have syntax specification... / What does those trailing do?

Comment: All the detail about how Jelly interprets the "input" (the code in your footer) is only necessary because of your test-suite implementation (using Jelly code to give the numbers) if you use an argument it is evaluated as Python code - see [this](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjnmOtv8Ptz9qWvP/v7GxkY6xsZ6RjqGRhZGxpYWJuY6BHhIbyDOAAR1DPUMY0NE11jM0MTS1NDIDMnUMUw1NAA) for example.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>12</s> 10 bytes

Match the format of a non-negative whole number

```
^\d+\.?0*$
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/O@uqpHA9T8uJkU7Rs/eQEvl/39jYyMuY2M9Iy5DIwsjY0sLE3MuAz0kNpBnAANchnqGMMCla6xnaGJoamlkBmQCAA)

*-2 thanks to FryAmTheEggman*

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <strike>7</strike> 4 bytes

Removed the unnecessary celing check after the solution of Erik The Outgolfer

```
<.=|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RczBCoAgEATQu18xdImgFl2tVPJrIokuHbzWt1sXdWBheAN75ZgQPCT@yxuFJw@iI/Qx@B4jXo@YhDj280aE1twq1a7YsnbWrEAhSRUrtU2W1A@kSgpNmpRRs@OlCfIH)

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp, <s>36</s> 32 bytes

```
(lambda(n)(=(max n 0)(floor n)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JLC74r1FQlJlXoqDxXyMnMTcpJVEjT1PDViM3sUIhT8FAUyMtJz@/SCFPU1Pzv7GeARgAmQA)

Transposition of [marmeladze’s answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/148480/41789).

Answer (score 2):

## [Symbolic Python](https://github.com/FTcode/Symbolic-Python), 21 bytes

```
_=_%(_==_)==(_!=_)<=_
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K67MTcrPyUzWLagsycjP@/8/3jZeVSPe1jZe09ZWI14RSNvYxv///1/XFAA)**

Uses a chained comparison:

- `_%(_==_) == (_!=_)` checks if `n%1 == 0`, only true if `n` has no decimal part.
- `(_!=_) <= _` checks if `0 <= n`, only true if the integer is non-negative.

Answer (score 2):

## [Implicit](//git.io/sS) (version predating challenge), 10 bytes

```
÷±1>?{;;ö}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87MLchJLS5JTM7@///w9kMbDe3sq62tD2@r/f9f19AIAA) (Will only work after Dennis pulls TIO for the eighteenth time, bugs are stupid)

```
÷±1>?{;;ö}   no implicit input :(
÷            read float
 ±1          push -1
   >         push (input > -1)
    ?{...}   if truthy
      ;      pop (input > -1)
       ;     pop -1
        ö    push iswhole(input)
             implicit integer output.
                if (input > -1) was false, it prints (input > -1).
                otherwise, it prints iswhole(input).
```

---

Posting this as an alternate solution since I had to update the builtin after realizing that whole numbers are >= 0, which feels cheaty.

## [Implicit](//git.io/sS), 1 byte

```
ö
```

Do *no* other languages have this builtin?!

```
   implicit float input
ö  push truthy if whole, falsy otherwise
   implicit int output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 17 bytes

```ruby
->n{n>=0&&n%1==0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc/dCoIwHAXwe5/ij5JXOvZhpRfzRaILk1lhDNEpxdyzrxVZEzqXPw4HTj@eHrbhNi2lliXHcSw3hHNsrBKDGoCDDhij8A0vQfWjSJwi6mtT3QbHhOaUFXm2X5Ux8vxXxgB/ljHCSzwliCzxJ1KGSEa2Bd3BmtfLHzbB@xYSVX0BPbfJNEM3up9hpFvzKka6ObRHk4C4d6JWV3l2NJnQ2Cc)

It's not great, but I don't think it can get smaller.

Answer (score 2):

## R, 30  <s>22</s> bytes

```
a=scan();`if`(a%%1==0&a>0,T,F)
```

Comment: It's a pity that we can't take strings as input, because `grepl("^\\d+.?0*$",scan(,""))` is 29 bytes. Ah well, +1.

Comment: You don't need the `if`: `a=scan();a>0&!a%%1` works for 18 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 7 bytes

```
⌋₁ℕ.&⌉₁
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pf/ahtw6Ompkcdy5VKikpTlWpArLTEnOJUpdqHWyeU/3/U0/2oqfFRy1Q9tUc9nUDm///RxsZGOsbGekY6hkYWRsaWFibmOgZ6SGwgzwAGdAz1DGFAJ95Yz9DE0NTSyAzIjAUA)

At first, I expected to submit a one-byte answer `ℕ`, which is a predicate meant to be equivalent to an assertion that the input (which is the output variable as well) is a whole number. Turns out, it doesn't consider integer-valued floats to be integers (throwing a false negative on the `0.00000000` test case, as well as the `1.0` non-test-case), so I had to do this instead:

```
           The input
⌋₁         rounded down
  ℕ        which is non-negative
   .       is the output variable
    &      and the input
     ⌉₁    rounded up
           is also the output variable.
```

Comment: Any number with a decimal separator is a float.

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 10 bytes

```
:1%$0(+0=n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/38pQVcVAQ9vANu////@6ZQq6xgA)

**Explanation**

Calculates `(n%1 + n<0) == 0`

Answer (score 2):

## TI-BASIC (TI-84), 3 bytes

```
not(fPart(Ans
```

**Example:**

```
3.5
             3.5
not(fPart(Ans
               0
21
              21
not(fPart(Ans
               1
```

Built-in functions are amazing, no?

Prints 0 (false) if `Ans` has a decimal part or 1 (true) if it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>6</s> <s>4</s> 3 bytes

```
¶Âa
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=tsJh&input=OC44)

---

### Explanation

Checks for strict equality (`¶`) between the input and the absolute value (`a`) of the input with bitwise NOT applied twice (`Â`).

Comment: Does it work for numbers > 2^31 ?

Answer (score 1):

## [Recursiva](https://github.com/officialaimm/recursiva), 4 bytes

```
=aIa
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pNLi0qzixL/P/fNtETSJrqGSADQwA)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>59</s> <s>57</s> 48  bytes

```py
print("1")if float(input())%1==0else print("0")
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ8lQSTMzTSEtJz@xRCMzr6C0RENTU9XQ1tYgNac4VQGqyEBJ8/9/YxMzk/8A)

Comment: Welcome to the site! You don't have to explicitly output `true` and `false`, instead you can output any two distinct values, such as 1 and 0, that are the same as true and false. Also, this answer can be golfed by removing unnecessary whitespace, and other such tricks found [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python)

Comment: Fails for [negative integers](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ8lQSTMzTSEtJz@xRCMzr6C0RENTU9XQ1tYgNac4VQGqyEBJ8/9/XeP/AA) (the requirement is to treat these as not-whole numbers).

Comment: Note that `eval` is shorter than `float` and will suffice here. Also you can put the `if` inside your `print`: `print("1"if eval(input())%1==0else"0")`. Furthermore you could use string indexing: `print("01"[eval(input())%1==0])`. But we don't need `"1"` and `"0"` at all: `print(eval(input())%1==0)`. A `lambda` would then save more: `lambda n:n%1==0` (not that any of this fixes the issue I noted above).

Comment: Why not just `print` the boolean directly? `print(float(input())%1==0)` Although the negative integer problem is pretty major.

Answer (score 1):

### D : 43 bytes

Just discovered that D has strange cast rules. Code :

```d
int w(float n){return n==cast(int)n&&n>=0;}
```

#### For testing

D : [Try it online](https://tio.run/##PU/RasMwDHzvVwg/lJh6xrG7rZ2X7UNCHsJib4ZUHo66PpR8e6asrAdCJ6Q7TsOSTt@5EEw0aK6U/ZKQ4FLFMfcEKK8l0LkgYNN89BNVvJW43eJbY/y8/OQ0wKlPWEm4boDxp2s7iNBAC85Z5Zy2UdX2YN3xsH9WRt95VIZHw@ADXd8R1YPT9b5@PNqnlUPnb@a5wJoAiN2N5/YKUY8BP@nLw25H/ylWXEqiMGIVW@qUYIFQ6188yXdB5RzEi4hjPwUhb@7zZl5@AQ)

D Code :

```d
void main() {
    float[] f = [ 332,33.2f,128239847,0.128239847f,0,0.0000f,1.1111111111f,-3.1415926f,-3 ];
    for (int t = 0; t < f.length; ++t) {
        writeln(f[t]," = ", w(f[t])?"true":"false");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, D has some weird casting rules for sure.

Answer (score 1):

## [MY](https://bitbucket.org/zacharyjtaylor/my-language), 8 bytes

```
ω≥ωω⌊=∧←
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y638//9856POpec7gVRPl@2jjuWP2ib8//8/WtdQx0DHUEfXQM9IB4hjAQ)

The link uses arrays to test multiple numbers at once.

### How?

- `ω≥` = `ω>=0` (`0` is popped when stack is empty)
- `ωω⌊=` = `ω==floor(ω)`
- `∧←` = take the logical and of the things above, then output.

Answer (score 1):

## Clojurescript, 12 bytes

```
#(=(int %)%)
```

No TIO, this doesn't work in Clojure, only Clojurescript. You can try it [here](http://clojurescript.net/) though:

```
cljs.user=> (def f #(=(int %)%))
#'cljs.user/f
cljs.user=> (f 2)
true
cljs.user=> (f 2.0)
true
cljs.user=> (f 2.5)
false
```

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 25 chars

```
(f:Double)=>f.ceil.abs==f
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the type definition cannot be excluded

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 24 bytes

```powershell
+"$args"-match'^[^-.]+$'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X1tJJbEovVhJNzexJDlDPS46TlcvVltF/f///7rGeoYmhqaWRmYA)

Convert the argument to a string, then back to a number (actually unnecessary, could have also just used `$args[0]` directly, but I thought of the latter first and it's the same byte count), then do a regex match, looking to see that the string has no `-` or `.` characters in its entirety.

Simple and boring :(

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 28 bytes

First solution:

```
echo!(ceil($n=$argv[1])-$n);
```

Second solution:

```
echo floor($n=$argv[1])==$n;
```

Comment: gives false positive for every negative int

Answer (score 1):

### [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 6 bytes

```
?~<%@'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/9@@zkbVQf3/f11jYyM9AwA)

Output via exit code. `1` for whole numbers and `0` otherwise.

#### Explanation

Unfolded:

```
 ? ~
< % @
 ' .
```

If we try to read two integers, then the second one will be zero for whole numbers.

```
?    Read whole number part, N.
~    Multiply by -1.
<    This branches depending on whether the value is positive or not, i.e.
     whether N is negative or not.

     If it's negative, the IP moves SE.

'    Move the memory pointer backwards, to the right.
?    Read another value. Irrelevant.
%    Computes (0 % N). Irrelevant.
~    Multiply by -1. Irrelevant.
@    Terminate the program.

     If N isn't negative, the IP moves NE from the <.

?    Read the fractional part, F.
'    Move the memory pointer backwards, to the right.
%    Computes (0 % F). This terminates the program with exit code 1 if
     F is zero. Otherwise, it does nothing.
~    Multiply by -1. Irrelevant.
<    Reflect the IP to SW.
~    Multiply by -1. Irrelevant.
%    Computes (0 % F). Now irrelevant.
'    Move the IP back again.
@    Terminate  the program.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth - 10 Bytes

```
&qQ.EQgQ0
```

Explanation :

```
              Implicitly Print
&              And
    q           Are Equal
        Q        Input
        .E       Ceiling of
            Q     Input
    g           Greater Than or Equal to
        Q        Input
        0         0
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ïÄQ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8PrDLYH//@saGukZGBgAAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpPCobZKCkn2ly//D6w@3BP7X@W9sbMRlbKxnxGVoZGFkbGlhYs5loIfEBvIMYIDLUM8QBrh0jfUMTQxNLY3MgEygbpAyLl0IDQA).

**Explanation:**

```python
ï      # Trim all decimals of the (implicit) input
 Ä     # Take its absolute value
  Q    # Check if it's equal to the (implicit) input (and output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Scratch in scratchblocks2, <s>92</s> 67 bytes

thanks lirtosiast

```
when gf clicked
ask[]and wait
say<([abs v]of(answer))=(round(answer
```

[Try it online](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/263192991/#editor)

Comment: Surely ```when gf clicked
ask[]and wait
say<([abs v]of(answer))=(round(answer``` is shorter?

Comment: Ah yes, somehow I forgot about that.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 23+1 bytes

```php
<?=$argn==abs(0|$argn);
```

prints `1` for truthy; empty output for falsy.
Run as pipe with `-F`.

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 18 characters

```
->x{x>=0&&0==x%1}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Commodore BASIC (C64/128 C64Mini VIC-20...) 17 tokenized BASIC bytes

```
 0INPUTA:?A=INT(A)
```

In Commodore (Microsoft) 8-BIT BASIC, `-1` is `TRUE` and `0` is `FALSE`.

If you require strictly `1` to represent `TRUE` and `0` to represent `FALSE`, this is how to do it:

#### Version 2, 20 tokenized BASIC bytes

```
 0INPUTA:?ABS(A=INT(A))
```

or

```
 0INPUTA:?-(A=INT(A))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
⌊=
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%8C%8A%3D&inputs=2.3&header=&footer=)

```
⌊  # Floor
 = # Is equal to original?
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 2 bytes

```
N=
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWi_xslxQnJRdDuQsWG-oZQJgA)

##### Explanation

```python
N=  # Implicit input
N   # Cast to integer
 =  # Equals the input?
    # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, <s>9</s> 12 bytes

```
n=>!n%1&n>=0
```

Didn't realize that I had to take in negatives. Pointed out by @kamoroso94.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 20 bytes

```
->x{x.div(1)==x.abs}
```

## Ruby, 22 bytes

```
->x{[0,x].max==x.to_i}
```

Comment: Why is there a leading space in the second code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

## C on Linux, 31 bytes

```
int f(float v){return!rintf(v);}
```

The correct prototype for rintf is `float rintf(float)`. However, in IEEE floating-point, 0.0f has the binary representation of all zeros. We (mis)use this feature to get away without using a prototype; the zero/non-zero value is then inverted into 1 or 0.

Comment: or `#define f(v)!rintf(v)`

Comment: You should be able to use the implicit int typing if you drop the `int`.

Comment: @technosaurus - Why not accept `double` and save a byte? `#define f(v)!rint(v)`

Comment: Actually, I don't think this answer is correct at all - should it be `v==rint(v)`?  Or perhaps `!fmod(v,1)`

Comment: @TobySpeight, it would have to be !fmodf(v,1.0) for the return to be a float (int-sized), and 1.0 to force the parameter to a float, both needed because there is no prototype.

Comment: I missed the bit where you said it only works on platforms where `int` is the same size as `float`.  I'll read more carefully in future!  It's still the case that this returns true for `0.5` and false for `2.0`, contrary to requirements.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jq 1.5](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 15 bytes

```
.>=0and.==floor
```

Not much to explain:

```
(. >= 0) and     # non-negative and
(. == floor)     # value == (value truncated to integer)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYxBDsIgFET3PQWJW/4P8Ku2C3oXEtukhkClEDeeXawxVfDt5s1krrdMpDj7coCBxZDGhggL/9aTsevYSNUp6rv2zKu5wLL4zUXxXc3FDi@0RLlTvQChbOWxVyfOav///vGPjIMWxl1Q68l6H3J@@iXO3q0ZwCVrYXZLilsI5g4@xS28AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [D](https://dlang.org/), <s>36</s> <s>33</s> 30 bytes

```d
T f(T)(T n){return(n<0)==n%1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S/n/P0QhTSNEUyNEIU@zuii1pLQoTyPPxkDT1jZP1dC69n9ZfmaKQm5iZp6GpkI1F2dmbkF@UYlCcUmKHhBn5ltzcZYXZZak5uRpKKVp6BpqKtgqKOmAWZqocgYwKQN0GbgmTD16cDkQEyhb@x8A)

I will not be beaten in D!

Answer (score 0):

## [Enlist](https://github.com/alexander-liao/enlist), 4 bytes

```
:1Ae
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83LySwu@f/fytAx9f///8bGRjrGxnpGOoZGFkbGlhYm5joGekhsIM8ABnQM9QxhQEfXWM/QxNDU0sgMyAQA)

Direct port of my Jelly answer above. Because of some reasons *[HyperNeutrino](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68942/hyperneutrino)* didn't implement 
Floor or Ceiling in Enlist, I use `:1` (integer division by 1) instead, which takes 2 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## Lua, 38 bytes

```
function f(n)print(n>=0 and n%1==0)end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3BCsIwEETvfsVehOwhYTep2h7ivwTbQKGsUpPvT61QSZzjPN7MkkMpMcsjzU@BqARf6yxJyd0TBBlBzuw94SRjico5i/CL1pDWPJ323lTg08ewvHfAtrdu6LsbtgKZmlQCVfutQEew7tnwkXZIO8MdXwZ7RfgD2D58QdkA)

Answer (score 0):

### REXX, 27 bytes

```
arg n
say trunc(n)=n & n>=0
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 17 bytes

```
{it%1==.0&&it>=0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bchBCoMwEEDRfU8xm0qyMERcCNIEWnqDnmAEI8F0IulYKOLZ06xb/@6/OXLwlN8YwPXiHtchjLK2txjDiAQG8ub53BijdFV5tkbv2a0ET/QkME2vHq4p4efy4ORpshK2E5SWchxIOKE6KX@obpX@Q31g3YE1WrUF9/wF)

Answer (score 0):

## C + [ecpp](//github.com/aaronryank/ecpp), 23 bytes

```
#def $x !fmod(x,1)&x>=0
```

Defines an operator `$` that takes one right operand `x` and evaluates to 1 if `x` is whole and 0 if it is not.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcvfCsIgHIbhc6/C3BoKOlodrnYlnYj6a4L/aBZCdOvZtu/sfeAzKiWhamODci9t8NXLPPfzVBttALcFH8BHTQsfWFem26nakLGXNtB3tJqhD8LrwEWZcRn3WJQMQMkRCO8KG9GO6bkeN9X3QHi7@beKS38efgqcfCxVOP8H)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://www.github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 4 bytes

Not a difficult question, but I thought I’d give it a try. Also did not think that zero was whole, but it saves a byte.

```
qs.a
```

Explanation:

```
 s.a      Integer of the absolute value of the implicit input
q         Is it the same as the original implicit input?
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=qs.a&input=0&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A1.1%0A0%0A0.0%0A-1%0A-1.1&debug=0)

Version that doesn’t find `0` as a whole number:

```
&qs.a
```

Ands the original answer with the input, so `0` falsifies the answer.

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%26qs.a&input=0&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A1.1%0A0%0A0.0%0A-1%0A-1.1&debug=0)

Returns a falsy or truthy value that isn’t always a Boolean.

Answer (score 0):

## Julia, 13 bytes

```
f(x)=x in 0:x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0/f8/TaNC07ZCITNPwcCq4n9BUWZeSU6eRpqGoYGmJheCa6xnhMLXNUHj6plpav4HAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [ARBLE](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ARBLE), <s>9</s> 7 bytes

```lua
nt(a%1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxKykn9/z@vRCNR1VDz////hnqGAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), <s>3</s> 4 bytes

```
Đ⎶Å≡
```

```
    implicit input
Đ   duplicates top value
⎶   pushes closest int to top value
Å   abs(TOS)
≡   checks if equal
    implicit output
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yIRHfdsOtz7qXPj/v64JFwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Taxi](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Taxi/), 553 bytes

```
Go to Post Office:w 1 l 1 r 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.Go to The Babelfishery:s 1 l 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Cyclone:n 5 l 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to Trunkers.Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.Go to Trunkers:s 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.Go to Equal's Corner:w 1 l.Switch to plan "b" if no one is waiting.'1' is waiting at Writer's Depot.[b]'0' is waiting at Writer's Depot.Go to Writer's Depot:n 1 l 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to Post Office:n 1 r 2 r 1 l.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVLBSsNAEP2VRy85uZjUCuZolR4tKHgQD5swSYYus3F3Q@zXx41JoVVo9bAs83be483sC/qTh2FjESy21gc8VRWXlPdIYeJx4622XO66Fhqt9p6kJofastQj66Uh3OuCTMW@IbdXk9hPOPcHxbNq631prNAsMle5YBW52SUnrpMdOX@26fGj0ybxWFsn5A5mZ@Zk8v/8U3BannruOZTN@NwaLVgUC3AFsYgTgT16zSGKqiRNjkrogFfHgVzUe6DWBvVWvCfXF3omH6dgXNtfVn707ep3EOQ7BNkchGG4Wqr0Jl3dZbdf)

Ungolfed:

```
Go to Post Office: west 1st left 1st right 1st left.
Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.
Go to The Babelfishery: south 1st left 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Go to Cyclone: north 5th left 2nd left.
Pickup a passenger going to Trunkers.
Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.
Go to Trunkers: south 1st left.
Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.
Go to Equal's Corner: west 1st left.
Switch to plan "b" if no one is waiting.
'1' is waiting at Writer's Depot.
[b]
'0' is waiting at Writer's Depot.
Go to Writer's Depot: north 1st left 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.
Go to Post Office: north 1st right 2nd right 1st left.
```

I'm surprised it took this long to post such a basic challenge. I like them. Taxi is... still not good for golfing.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
Ḟ⁼A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjnmPGvc4/v//X9dYzwQA)

Uses [Erik's strategy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/148470/77748) of `floor(n) == abs(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
AḞ=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/x4Y55tv///zc0MDDQMwABAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 73 bytes

```
	DEFINE('W(N)D')
W	N SPAN('1234567890') '.' REM . D
	W =EQ(D) 1	:(RETURN)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcyxDsIgEADQGb7itrtbSIGi1aSDCWfiIFaEsDsbO/j/QdfG8S3v816f62vs6kiFu4pyviQhbJQ4IuumEjyWUyK0zo9ht58OAzKgQchyBQNRqwaz3Cky2F@SpdScuJe/St1qWWqBuZHfytiNB@eDC96xlhT7Fw)

An anonymous function; returns `1` for truthy and an empty string for falsey.

Takes `N` the input and matches it against the regex `\\d.(\\d*)$`, setting `(\\d*)` as `D`. Then if `D==0` (`''==0` in SNOBOL), sets `W` to `1`. If not, it doesn't set `W`, which defaults to the empty string, and returns `W`.

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript - 16 Bytes

`a=>a>=0&&a%1<=0`

```js
f=a=>a>=0&&a%1<=0

// ----------- Test Cases -------------

console.log(332, f(332))
console.log(33.2, f(33.2))
console.log(128239847, f(128239847))
console.log(0.128239847, f(0.128239847))
console.log(0, f(0))
console.log(0.000000000, f(0.000000000))
console.log(1.111111111, f(1.111111111))
console.log(-3.1415926, f(-3.1415926))
console.log(-3, f(-3))
```

Comment: Fails on `3` and `-3.1415926`

Answer (score 0):

## TI-BASIC, 5 bytes

Takes input and gives output through `Ans`.

```
Ans=abs(int(Ans
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (SpiderMonkey)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Releases/45), 24 bytes

```javascript
s=>s<0?0:s==Math.ceil(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY1NDoIwEEb3nqSzYNIfUDBWT@AhmlK0WilhiImnH1dsLPEt3/uS7@Hejvwcp6WiKfZhfuXxGT48WCZ7ppO8yCNZe3XLHX2ISRCwzyPlFDDlmxiEMRpg9@uwlEq32nRtfSiKxD9tYy1Xyg9UK0WrDKpaNZ3ebyQA5i8)

A great thanks to [@Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king) for converting the code from 29bytes to 24.

Comment: @JoKing thanks for pointing out.

Comment: `false` can be `0` and I'm pretty sure `===` can be `==`

Comment: @JoKing yes. that way I will reduce 1 byte.

Comment: and four bytes for `false` to `0`.. or if you're really insistent on booleans rather than falsey values, at least do `0>1`

Comment: @JoKing the output requires false. If think that way then 0 is not significant option.

Comment: No, if you look closer, it requires a [falsey value](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2194/60919), of which zero is an example

Comment: but the output will be differ from what he excepted.Is that ok in rules of codegolf.

Comment: The test cases only show an example of input and output, not the exact expectations. The question asks for a truthy/falsey value, which could be anything like `1 0`, `true false`, `'' 'non-empty string'` or any mixture of  those

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>59</s> <s>60</s> 57 bytes

```python
lambda s:re.match(r"^\+?[0-9]+(\.0*)?$",s)>None
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5NDoIwEEbX9hRN4wIEmv6gAglyAy8AmKCWQCItabvx9DUU2Pht3rzJTGbmrx2UZK4vG/fppue7g6bQAk@dfQ2BRo8mqmqS5G0UNJicwuqIYhPe7koKME6z0hZq4aww1sAS1uCAOGco9sRrQVnGeJ6lV28E//nWJXvWHUz3eE84pik95@yy6XoCbyA7l@kWgF5puPwER@lpCnCY9Sittxj2wcLQ/QA)

Takes input as a string.

Regex is as follows:

- starts with + or a number
- has AT LEAST 1 digit
- either:

  - has a period, but only zeroes follow the period
  - has a period, but nothing after the period
  - terminates without a period

Python 2's re.match objects are greater than None objects, so it will return True if the regex matched and False otherwise.

Edit: no longer has false positives on negative numbers (not sure what i was thinking...) and correctly handles trailing periods. Thanks, [Deadcode](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17216/deadcode)!

<sup><sub>I feel so bad about the greater than None check.</sub></sup>

Comment: This is incorrect. The problem defines a whole number as a non-negative integer, so you need `\+?` (or nothing) not `[+-]?`. Also, shouldn't it be `0*` not `0+`? Ending with a decimal point is generally valid.

Comment: @Deadcode Well, crap. You're right. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 3 bytes

```
i±=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/z/z0Ebb//@NjY24jI31jLgMjSyMjC0tTMy5DPSQ2ECeAQxwGeoZwgCXrrGeoYmhqaWRGZD5HwA)

### Explanation

Same as a bunch of other answers.

```
i     Read input as integer
 ±    Convert to absolute value
  =   Is it equal to the implicit input?
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 17 bytes

```
I:0(q0h:S(-zq1!0h
```

A simple solution, but I will be golfing this *alot* more

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/39PKQKPQIMMqWEO3qtBQ0QAopGsIAA)

Comment: [7 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/39MqV1O1Csgw1DMCAA), with error/0 as falsey, 1 as truthy. If you don't like that than you can at least get rid of no-ops (like `q1!0` lol) and switch to modulo-1 for [10 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/39MqV7PWULVKC8jWNQQA)

Comment: @JoKing Those look really good, I honestly didn't realize that the '0' wasn't doing anything! I feel like such an idiot, in a little while I'll add your programs on (attributed to you of course)

Comment: @KrystosTheOverlord in a little while? :P

Answer (score 0):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 6 bytes

```
i:kn=@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/z/TKjvP1uH/f11TAA)

Works on inputs up to 65535. Compares the input with the input cast to character and back to number. Inputs larger than 65535 cast to char exceed the byte size and roll over.

Answer (score 0):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), 4 bytes

```
?$-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/315F1/D/fwMA)

### Explanation

```
?        Given input n, output true if n is in the sequence and false if it is not
         Each term in the sequence equals
 $        current index
  -1                    - 1
```

The `-1` in to include `0` - if the challenge just wanted positive integers, `?$` would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 2 bytes

```
1%
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=1%25&i=332%0A33.2%0A128239847%0A0.128239847%0A0%0A0.000000000%0A1.111111111%0A-3.1415926%0A-3&a=1&m=2)

Modulus by 1.